# Yii2 : Dataprovider append query issue in controller

Tags: php, yii2

I have append query in controller using dataprovider object but my last query is not apply after used getKeys() method.

Why without `getKeys()` method is possible but with `getKeys()` not possible?

Please view my below code.

```
$searchModel = new MySearchModel();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->sort = false;

$pKey = $dataProvider->getKeys();
$otherId = MyModel::find()->andWhere(['id' => $pKey])->select('id')->column();

//This query is not apply/append when i used `getKeys()` method
$dataProvider->query->andWhere(['id' => $otherId]);


return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Comment: Show your MySearchModel  code and the code where you define the getKeys() function please

Comment: @scaisEdge `getKeys()` function is 'ActiveDataProvider' function not in `MySearchModel` class.